# Move constructor for a value/object wrapper?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, assignment-operator, move-semantics

Consider the following class:

```
template <typename Type>
class Wrapper
{
    public:
        Wrapper(const Type& x) : _data(x) {;}
        Wrapper<Type>& operator=(const Type& x) {_data = x; return *this;}
    protected:
        Type _data;
};
```

What would be the definition of the move constructor `Wrapper(Type&& x)` and the move assignment operator `operator=(Type&& x)` of this class ?

Comment: No need to spell out the template argument in the class definition; it's implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Wrapper(Type&& x) : _data(std::move(x)) {}
Wrapper& operator=(Type&& x) {_data = std::move(x); return *this;}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to write this in C++11 is:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename T=void*>
using IfSameBaseType = std::enable_if<
  typename std::is_same<
    typename std::remove_cv<A>::type,
    typename std::remove_cv<B>::type
  >::type,
  T
>::type;

template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
  public:
    template<typename U, typename unused>
    Wrapper(U&& u, unused* do_not_use=(IfSameBaseType<T,U>*)nullptr) :
      data_( std::forward(u) )
    {}
    template<typename U>
    IfSameBaseType<T,U,Wrapper<Type>>& operator=(U&& x) {
      data_ = std::forward(x);
      return *this;
    }
  protected:
    T data_;
};
```

here, I use `&&` in a type deduction context to provide a single override for l and r value references, which I then pass on via `std::forward`.  The `IsSameBaseType` stuff just makes sure that I only write constructors for the type `T` -- I could extend this and say "is implicitly convertible to T" instead of `IsSameBaseType` without all that much hassle.

The advantage of this is that we have fewer duplicate methods.  The disadvantage is all that template tomfoolery could distract someone from the point of it all.